# Как убрать точку из введенного пользователем списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача следующая: нужно вывести сортированный по алфавиту список слов, которые ввел пользователь.
Важный нюанс - слова, не должны выводится с пунктуационными знаками.

Программа работает, слова выводятся. Но я никак не могу избавиться от точки. Метод replace, remove не работают (вернее у меня не получается их правильно использовать). Подскажите, как добиться вывода отсортированных слов без точки! Спасибо!

```
y = []
while True:
    user_input = input('type text')
    divide_string = user_input.split()

    for x in divide_string:
        y.append(x)
    if user_input == '':
        break
    else:
        continue

print(" ".join(sorted(y)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
...
punctuation_map = {ord(char): None for char in string.punctuation}
while True:
    user_input = input('type text')
    clean_data = user_input.translate(punctuation_map)
    divide_string = clean_data.split()
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
import re

# исходные данные
user_input = 'type text. hello'
# с помощью регулярных выражений извлечем только слова длиной больше 3 символов
worlds = re.findall('\w{3,}', user_input)
# сортируем и выводим
print(sorted(worlds))
```

Получаем

```
['hello', 'text', 'type']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y = []
while True:
    user_input = input('type text: ')
    divide_string = user_input.split()

    for x in divide_string:
        y.append(x.replace('.', ''))
    if user_input == '':
        break
    else:
        continue

print(" ".join(sorted(y)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import punctuation

def y(lj=lambda w: ''.join(s for s in w if s not in punctuation)):
    user_input = input('type text')
    while user_input:
        yield from map(lj, user_input.split())
        user_input = input('type text')

print(*sorted(y()))
```